# NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey can not be set correctly

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to prevent a whole folder from beeing backed up by itunes. I followed the Technical Report http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html But it seems that falg is everytime nil. I use IOS 5.1 tried in in simulator and on device. But nothing helps. The methods return "success" every time, but flag is still nil.

```
+ (BOOL) hasSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    NSError *error = nil;

    id flag = nil;
    BOOL success = [URL getResourceValue: &flag
                                  forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];

    if(!success){

        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
        return false;
    }

    if (!flag)
        return false;

    return [flag boolValue];
}

+ (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    NSError *error = nil;

    BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                                  forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];

    if(!success){

        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);

    }

    return success;

}

+ (BOOL)removeSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    NSError *error = nil;

    BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO]
                                  forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];

    if(!success){

        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);

    }

    return success;

}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I just fixed this in my app and while it was kind of frustrating , it all ended up working great.
So , here's the code for the [addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL](https://gist.github.com/1999985) . You may want to check that out. It treats 5.0.1 and 5.0 too. You are only treating 5.1 and higher in your code.

**BUT:**

Let's say you have an NSString *path - the path to your file /folder , **don't call the method with**:

`[NSURL urlWithString:path];` *It will work on 5.0.1 but not on 5.1  and higher.*

Instead `use [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];`

So: **[MyClass addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];**

In fact , I think that is the only problem with your code. Taking the method I linked to , will only provide backward compatibility , which is a great addition.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
George

Comment: brilliant you saved my morning!

Comment: Thanks!!! FWIW, I put in a bug report to Apple... It should at least give an error if it doesn't work.

Comment: Well that's definitely not idiosyncratic and weird or anything.... Thank you SO MUCH for this answer!!! Totally saved me a ton of grief.

Comment: In my app deployment target is 6.0, that the region to reject app because I am using [NSURL urlWithString:path]; instead of [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]

Answer (score 2):

Same problem for me. 
I also solved it changing the way I called addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL
That's the correct way:

```
[MyClass addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
```