# How to set NSURL Resource Values for all files and folders within a folder

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurl

I'm trying to prevent a whole folder and its contents from backing up to iCloud, by setting its `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` to `1`, as indicated in the [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html). I'm able to set the key to the folder's URL, but all the data I then save inside it has `0` for its `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey`...

Here's my code:

```
//create the directory:
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
NSURL *folderURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:YES];

//prevent backup:
NSError *preventBackupError = nil;
BOOL success = [folderURL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                                    forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey
                                     error: &preventBackupError];        

//this prints 1 and 1:
NSLog(@"resource values for directory: %@", [folderURL resourceValuesForKeys:@[NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey, NSURLIsDirectoryKey] error:nil]);
```

Now, if I then save a file (in this case it's `config.xml`) inside a subdirectory of `folderURL` and then do:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"config.xml"]];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileURL.path]) {
    NSLog(@"resource values for config file: %@", [configURL resourceValuesForKeys:@[NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey] error:nil]);
}
```

This prints `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey = 0;`

I checked other SO answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836134/nsurlisexcludedfrombackupkey-can-not-be-set-correctly), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866590/prevent-icloud-backup-of-folder), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928509/cfurlsetresourcepropertyforkey-failed-when-disable-data-backup-on-nsdocumentdire), I can't see any difference in my syntax...

So my question is, do I have to manually set that key to every single file inside the folder? Or am I doing something wrong?

Cheers

Comment: Can I assume that your directory is inside the "Application Support" folder? I imagine setting the flag on the new folder should work, you don't have evidence to the contrary, and I can see no reason that the flag would be set on individual files within the folder. You should look and see if they are excluded or not - they surely are. Apple says this in the iOS App Orig. Guide: "Applying this attribute prevents the files from being backed up .... If you have a large number of support files, you may store them in a custom subdirectory and apply the extended attribute to just the directory."

Comment: I thought that the attribute would be applied recursevely to all the files within the folder... But you're right, the docs do say that the attribute can be applied to just the folder: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW28

Answer (score 1):

Cocoa doesn't have a built-in single method for applying properties recursively to a resource and its descendants. I imagine some of the reason is to simplify error handling. But also, doing this is pretty rare.

Fortunately, it's pretty easy to build your own:

1. Apply desired property to the directory resource in question
2. Ask `NSFileManager` for a directory enumerator
3. Enumerate through all items (by default, `NSDirectoryEnumerator` will descend into all subdirectories for you), applying property to each of them too

It does seem this isn't needed in your case though; apply `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` to the directory, and be done with it.